i am publishing an update on google console after modify USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission for android 14 but my update is rejected. below is the SS
play console rejection email screenshot here I am showing Alert dialog to ask user for permission and navigate user to settings to enable the permission.
This permission is necessary for my app. my app has functionality for video calling and i am using it to notify user of incoming calls.

From https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/fsi-limits:

[The] default USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission to send full-screen notifications can be granted only to apps that provide calling and alarm functionalities.

Make sure your app is classified correctly in Google Play.
